# Php array - merge only specific keys in single array,

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 4
                )
         [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 4
                )

        )

)
```

I want to merge only specific keys as below, Key 0 and 1 are merged as a single array. Like this I want.

In the below example, keys 0 and 1 are merged, it can be changing, so I want custom.. please help me

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 3
                    [3] => 4
                )
         [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 4
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Where are you stuck at?

Comment: Actually, I have a big multidimensional array where I want to merge only specific keys, so I gave the above example one.

Comment: With each keys I'm creating a table, so some keys are seperated, so I'm trying to merge them

Comment: I know the keys which are all to be merged, but I don't know how to merge them.

Answer (score 0):

This script will help you

```php
<?php

$array = [
    [
        [
            1,
            2,
        ],
        [
            3,
            4,
        ],
        [
            3,
            4,
        ]
    ]
];

array_unshift($array[0], array_merge($array[0][0], $array[0][1]));
unset($array[0][1]);
unset($array[0][2]);
print_r($array);
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 3
                    [3] => 4
                )
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 4
                )
        )
)
```

First use `array_merge` to merge the elements and then use `array_unshift` to push the new element to array and then use `unset` to remove the old elements